# Firestore - How to join root collections in queries?

Tags: join, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore imagine a "shops", a "orders" and a "buyers" root collection.

How do I query orders and join with shop.title and buyer.name ?

Can I then also do a - where buyer.age > 30 ?

Basically the question is - does firestore support joins in queries ?

Comment: which api you are using? provide question with some code.

Comment: There is no support for server-side joins in Firestore. You'll have to perform those joins on the client.